# Showing images in placeholder on focus

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I have an image displayed on placeholder and this image hide after focusing it. How it can be done the solution for not to hide the image after focusing?

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Catchamouse/8bq8eoke/2/

html

```
    <title>Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3</title>


    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Codrops top bar -->
            <div class="codrops-top">
                <a href="">
                    <strong>&laquo; Previous Demo: </strong>Responsive Content Navigator
                </a>
                <span class="right">
                    <a href=" http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/27/login-and-registration-form-with-html5-and-css3/">
                        <strong>Back to the Codrops Article</strong>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->
            <header>
                <h1>Login and Registration Form <span>with HTML5 and CSS3</span></h1>
                <nav class="codrops-demos">
                    <span>Click <strong>"Join us"</strong> to see the form switch</span>
                    <a href="index.html" class="current-demo">Demo 1</a>
                    <a href="index2.html">Demo 2</a>
                    <a href="index3.html">Demo 3</a>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <section>               
                <div id="container_demo" >
                    <!-- hidden anchor to stop jump http://www.css3create.com/Astuce-Empecher-le-scroll-avec-l-utilisation-de-target#wrap4  -->
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="login" class="animate form">
                            <form  action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 
                                <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname">Your email or username </label>
                                    <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd"> Your password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
                                    <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                                </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">
                                    Not a member yet ?
                                    <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div id="register" class="animate form">
                            <form  action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
                                    <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/> 
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                                </p>
                                <p class="signin button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">  
                                    Already a member ?
                                    <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
/* remove codrops styles and reset the whole thing */
#container_demo{
     text-align: left;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-family: "Trebuchet MS","Myriad Pro",Arial,sans-serif;
}

/** fonts used for the icons **/ 
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontomasCustomRegular';
    src: url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/fontomas-webfont.svg#FontomasCustomRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FranchiseRegular';
    src: url('fonts/franchise-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/franchise-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/franchise-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/franchise-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/franchise-bold-webfont.svg#FranchiseRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
a.hiddenanchor{
    display: none;
}
/** The wrapper that will contain our two forms **/
#wrapper{
    width: 60%;
    right: 0px;
    min-height: 560px;  
    margin: 0px auto;   
    width: 500px;
    position: relative; 
}
/**** Styling the form elements **/

/**** general text styling ****/
#wrapper a{
    color: rgb(95, 155, 198);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#wrapper h1{
    font-size: 48px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    padding: 2px 0 10px 0;
    font-family: 'FranchiseRegular','Arial Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
/** For the moment only webkit supports the background-clip:text; */
#wrapper h1{
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
    rgb(18, 83, 93) , 
    rgb(18, 83, 93) 20px, 
    rgb(64, 111, 118) 20px, 
    rgb(64, 111, 118) 40px, 
    rgb(18, 83, 93) 40px);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
#wrapper h1:after{
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,100,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,100,255,0.8) 20%, rgba(0,100,255,1) 53%, rgba(0,100,255,0.8) 79%, rgba(0,100,255,0) 100%); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(147,184,189,0)), color-stop(20%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8)), color-stop(53%,rgba(147,184,189,1)), color-stop(79%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8)), color-stop(100%,rgba(147,184,189,0))); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(147,184,189,0) 0%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 20%,rgba(147,184,189,1) 53%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 79%,rgba(147,184,189,0) 100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(147,184,189,0) 0%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 20%,rgba(147,184,189,1) 53%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 79%,rgba(147,184,189,0) 100%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(147,184,189,0) 0%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 20%,rgba(147,184,189,1) 53%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 79%,rgba(147,184,189,0) 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(147,184,189,0) 0%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 20%,rgba(147,184,189,1) 53%,rgba(147,184,189,0.8) 79%,rgba(147,184,189,0) 100%); 
}

#wrapper p{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#wrapper p:first-child{
    margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper label{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    position: relative;
}

/**** advanced input styling ****/
/* placeholder */
::-webkit-input-placeholder  { 
    color: rgb(190, 188, 188); 
    font-style: italic;
}
input:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder{ 
    color: rgb(190, 188, 188);
    font-style: italic;
} 
input {
  outline: none;
}

/* all the input except submit and checkbox */
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]){
    width: 92%;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 32px;    
    border: 1px solid rgb(178, 178, 178);
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
      -moz-box-sizing : content-box;
           box-sizing : content-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.6) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.6) inset;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.6) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):active,
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):focus{
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,100,255,0.7);
    background: rgba(0,255,255,1);  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.9) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.9) inset;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.9) inset;
} 

/** the magic icon trick ! **/
    [data-icon]:after {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    font-family: 'FontomasCustomRegular';
    color: rgb(106, 159, 171);
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 35px;
    width: 30px;
}

/*styling both submit buttons */
#wrapper p.button input{
    width: 30%;
    cursor: pointer;    
    background: rgba(0,50,200,1);
    padding: 8px 5px;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular','Arial Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;    
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);  
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px; 

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#wrapper p.button input:hover{
    background: rgba(0,100,255,1);
}
#wrapper p.button input:active,
#wrapper p.button input:focus{
    background: rgba(0,255,255,1);
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);  

}
p.login.button,
p.signin.button{
    text-align: right;
    margin: 5px 0;
}


/* styling the checkbox "keep me logged in"*/
.keeplogin{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.keeplogin input,
.keeplogin label{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;    
    font-style: italic;
}
.keeplogin input#loginkeeping{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.keeplogin label{
    width: 80%;
}


/*styling the links to change from one form to another */

p.change_link{
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(127, 124, 124);
    left: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 440px;
    padding: 17px 30px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 16px ;
    text-align: right;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(219, 229, 232);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0  5px 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 0 0  5px 5px;
            border-radius: 0 0  5px 5px;
    background: rgb(225, 234, 235);
    background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) , 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 15px, 
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 15px, 
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 30px, 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 30px
    );
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) , 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 15px, 
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 15px, 
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 30px, 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 30px
    );
    background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) , 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 15px, 
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 15px, 
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 30px, 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 30px
    );
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) , 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 15px, 
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 15px, 
    rgb(225, 234, 235) 30px, 
    rgb(247, 247, 247) 30px
    );
}
#wrapper p.change_link a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgb(247, 248, 241);
    padding: 2px 6px;
    color: rgb(29, 162, 193);
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(203, 213, 214);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s  linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s  linear;
    transition: all 0.4s  linear;
}
#wrapper p.change_link a:hover {
    color: rgb(57, 191, 215);
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    border: 1px solid rgb(74, 179, 198);
}
#wrapper p.change_link a:active{
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
/** Styling both forms **/
#register, 
#login{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 88%; 
    padding: 18px 6% 60px 6%;
    margin: 0 0 35px 0;
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109,  0.7),  0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109,  0.7),  0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
            box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7),0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(20,20,20,0.4) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
         border-radius: 5px;
}
#register{  
    z-index: 21;
    opacity: 0;
}
#login{
    background: rgba(0,0,80,1);
    z-index: 22;
}
#toregister:target ~ #wrapper #register,
#tologin:target ~ #wrapper #login{
    z-index: 22;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -ms-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .1s;
    -o-animation-delay: .1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: .1s;
    animation-delay: .1s;
}
#toregister:target ~ #wrapper #login,
#tologin:target ~ #wrapper #register{
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
    -ms-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
    -o-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
    animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
}

/** the actual animation, credit where due : http://daneden.me/animate/ ***/
.animate{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;

    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;

    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;

    -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;

    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

/** yerk some ugly IE fixes 'cause I know someone will ask "why does it look ugly in IE?", no matter how many warnings I will put in the article */

.lt8 #wrapper input{
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 32px;
    width: 92%;
}
.lt8 #wrapper input[type=checkbox]{
    width: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.lt8 #wrapper h1{
    color: #066A75;
}
.lt8 #register{ 
    display: none;
}
.lt8 p.change_link,
.ie9 p.change_link{
    position: absolute;
    height: 90px;
    background: transparent;
}

input#username
{
background-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/ct6blnyl9/user.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:5px 5px;        
text-indent: 0px;
}

input#password
{
background-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3mo0ydtct/password.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:5px 5px;        
text-indent: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the background color.

```
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):active, #wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):focus {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the background image on focus in your CSS:

```
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):focus{
background: rgba(0,255,255,1);  
}
```

Don't do that and it stays there.

Comment: Could you mark one of the answers as the correct one? It helps people looking for a similar problem and we get some bacon :)